# Help with Spring and JMS. I am trying to setup a simple publisher using spring?

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

So I have the following publisher:

```
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.Topic;

import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

public class JmsTopicSender {

    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    private Topic topic;

    public void setTopic(Topic topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public void simpleSend() {
        this.jmsTemplate.send(this.topic, new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                return session.createTextMessage("hello Topic");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So Im now stuck setting up the bean declarations. I know I need a JMSTemplate:

```
<bean id="jms-template" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connection-factory" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="destination" />
</bean>
```

But I dont know how to set the connection factory or destination up. There isnt even an example in the spring docs.

Answer (score 3):

Your connection factory can be standalone:

```
<bean id="connection-factory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
<property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:12345"/>
</bean>
```

Or you can retrieve it from JNDI:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="connection-factory" jndi-name="jms/ConnFactory"/>
```

Same for your destination:

```
<bean:id="myQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
<constructor-arg value="queue.my"/>
</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="myQueue" jndi-name="jms/MyQueue"/>
```

Comment: This helps however I am using a Tibco topic. This means I have a number of properties that I need to configure for the connection. brokerURL, topic, username, password?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your welcome. You can express your gratitude also by pressing the little upward triangle next to the answer :)

Comment: Off course! However I was awating your reply to see if you'd help get the issue solved! If you can answer my question you will get even more votes ;-)

Comment: For what would you need a username and a password for?

Comment: have you seen this tutorial?: http://allenpaulsblog.blogspot.com/2010/10/integrating-spring-jms-with-tibco-ems.html

Comment: Yes but it seems to massivley over complicate things and also doesnt use the recommended (boierplate) code form the spring docs. Ideally I want these two files the bean config.xml and a bootstrapper to start the process and send a message